# what does matroid structure mean in this answer?

Tags: matroids

what does *matroid structure* mean in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/151715)? I looked it up in Wikipedia but don't know which part applies to this case. What does the reply mean by "verify something forms a matroid structure"?

Comment: David's answer describes exactly what this means immediately below that sentence.

Comment: It means precisely that the points 1. 2. and 3. given in the answer there are satisfied.

Comment: For future reference, you could have asked this as a comment under David's answer.

Comment: @Qiaochu/Alastair: Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbered points are checking off that [these three axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Independent_sets.2C_bases.2C_and_circuits) for the definition of a matroid are satisfied.